# How to convert Application.PrevInstance in VB 6.0 to VB.NET?

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I have 'Applications.PrevInstance' in VB 6 code that I am trying to upgrade to .NET using VS 2008.  Apparently this code is no longer valid.  Does anyone have any ideas about upgraded solution? TIA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See here:

http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/previnstance.html

```
Public Sub Main()
   If PrevInstance() Then Exit Sub

   ' continue with your application
   UserName = Environ("UserName")
   ComputerName = Environ("COMPUTERNAME")

End Sub

Function PrevInstance() As Boolean
  If UBound(Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName _
     (Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName)) _
     > 0 Then
     Return True
  Else
     Return False
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you!  works perfectly!  Wondering if you know of a similar work around for dealing with Unload?

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/349334-whats-equivalent-unload-form1-vb-net

Comment: You have saved this poor mortal C# developer an aneurysm thanks to the imperfect VB code im tasked to port.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function PrevInstance() As Boolean
    If UBound(Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName)) > 0 Then
        PrevInstance = True
    Else
        UserName = Environ("UserName")
        Computername = Environ("COMPUTERNAME")
        PrevInstance = False
    End If
    Dim i, n As Integer, RepForm As String
    For i = My.Application.OpenForms.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
        RepForm = My.Application.OpenForms.Item(i).Name
        For n = My.Application.OpenForms.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If My.Application.OpenForms.Item(n).Name = My.Application.OpenForms.Item(i).Name And n > i Then
                My.Application.OpenForms(i).Close()
                PrevInstance = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next n
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: in the Function above you have two functions: the first for the App.exe itself and the second for the forms in the app.exe.
So you need to choose which you need and separate them in your app.
Ricky